# Using C datatypes with ctypes in python

Tags: python, ctypes

I tried to use C char pointer datatype in python 3.3. I used following code:

```
    from ctypes import *

    firstname = c_char_p("I am a noob programmer".encode("utf-8"))
    print(firstname.value)
```

My desired output was

```
    I am a noob programmer
```

but what I got was

```
    b'I am a noob programmer'
```

I am following a tutorial made for python 2.6. I used "ascii" as the parameter for encode function. And also tried the "bytes()" instead of encode. But no difference at either time.Why don't I get my desired output? and How can I get the output as desired.

Please anybody help me to understand..

Comment: The output is correct for Python 3. Use Python 2.6 if you want to see the same output as the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3 you need to decode it back to `str` if you want it to behave like `str`.

```
print(firstname.value.decode("utf-8"))
```